# Jquery Ajax Request Called Twice and the first request does not send token in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to call a WCF REST based service.

The ajax method is called before the page gets loaded.
I wish to send a "Token" in the header of ajax request. In fiddler this is what I see:

1.)A request to the service without the token in the header.(AJAX Call failure)
2.)A request to the same service with the token in the header.(AJAX Call Passed)

After that everything works fine on chrome and safari. But there is only one service call on IE 10 and Mozilla. As a result the service call fails in IE 10 and Mozilla since there is no token in the header of the request.

This is the method that I call:

```
function callservice (method, serviceUrl, params, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: method,
        url: serviceUrl,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", Token); },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
    function photos(data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    };
}
```

I control both the Web Service and the application(Which calls this Web Service). This problem does not arise when both the application and web service are hosted on the local host.In that case there is only one successful service call. But there are two AJAX calls when there is a cross domain call.

My question is why doesn't the AJAX request send the token in the first attempt?
And why does the token get sent only in the second AJAX call?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call that function from?

Comment: `service call fails in IE 10 and Safari` should read `IE 10 and Mozilla` right?

Comment: I call the function before the document load in: $(document).ready(function () {
       
    });

Comment: Your last comment is contradictory.

Comment: My guess is that you have logic to hook up an event handler that gets called dynamically (e.g. when an element gets created).  The event handler is hooked up to everything that matches your selector, even if the handler has already been assigned to a selected element.  Thus you'll get the same event firing multiple times.  Just a theory until you show how you're calling `callservice`.

Comment: Are you using CORS since it is crossdomain? Are you setting the right headers. There will be two calls for a handshake [aka Preflighted requests]

Comment: How do I include CORS to make the cross domain call??

Comment: @AndrewHubbs:I edited my last comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with CORS.Earlier,browsers did not allow ajax requests to be made to a domain which is different than that of a client as it was considered as a security threat.Modern browser's can make cross domain ajax request's as long as the server co-operates with the client.So this is what actually happens when there is a cross domain request from a browser:

1.)First the browser sends 'Preflight' request to the service to gather authorization information(which was a request with the header method as 'OPTIONS' in my case) from the WCF service. In return the Web Service sends Access Control Allow Origin as a part of its response header.And the error being displayed on fiddler as a result of this request was a HTTP 500 error.This AJAX request has nothing in the data field since it was just a way to find the authorization details of the WCF service.

2.)Chrome and Safari then made a second request to the Web Service now that they have the authorization details of the service.Whereas Firefox and IE did not prefer to make a second ajax request to the service since there was an HTTP 500 error for the pre-flight request. Hence both Chrome and Safari were able to communicate with the service.

So the solution was to modify the response from the WCF service in case there is a 'Preflight request' made to it.I modified the response sent by the service in case there is a 'Preflight request' to send an HTTP 200 OK Response. This allowed browsers like IE and Mozilla to send the actual request after the preflight request.

Here is one of the sources which I referred:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm

Hope this helps people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain call is under the same origin policy. You can not make the calls by default. You need to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) or JSONP or a proxy.

Comment: But the Web Service calls are successful in Chrome and Safari.Is there something that I need to do to fix up this problem on IE 10 and Mozilla?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: And secondly fiddler also shows the same error since the token is missing in the header which is required in order to make a successful service call.

Answer (score -1):

XMLHttpRequest: Unless they changed it, With MS Explorer you'll need to use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"). For my ajax call made in plain JS, i use this line to create the object according tyo the browser:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
   //for most BRowsers
   r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} else{ 
   //for Explorer
   r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

then apply your beforesend to the object created here (r) in my case. I truely believe this is your issue with EI. But not tested.

Comment: First the poster is making an Ajax call with jQuery. Second. IE8+ have native XMLHttpRequest support. This answer has nothing to do with the problem.